# how to convert csv to dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

How can I convert a csv into a dictionary using pandas? For example I have 2 columns, and would like column1 to be the key and column2 to be the value. My data looks like this:

```
"name","position"
"UCLA","73"
"SUNY","36"

cols = ['name', 'position']
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names = cols)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the columns to a list, then zip and convert to a dict:

```
In [37]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['first','second','third'], 'col2':np.random.rand(3)})
print(df)
dict(zip(list(df.col1), list(df.col2)))
     col1      col2
0   first  0.278247
1  second  0.459753
2   third  0.151873

[3 rows x 2 columns]
Out[37]:
{'third': 0.15187291615699894,
 'first': 0.27824681093923298,
 'second': 0.4597530377539677}
```

Answer (score 21):

Since the 1st line of your sample csv-data is a "header",
you may read it as `pd.Series` using the `squeeze` keyword of [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, header=None, squeeze=True).to_dict()
{'UCLA': 73, 'SUNY': 36}
```

If you want to include also the 1st line, remove the `header` keyword (or set it to `None`).

Comment: Could I ask why `squeeze`, please?

Comment: Because then it reads 2-column CSVs as series, as explained, which has the `to_dict()` method, so it's supposed to be more efficient than populating a full dataframe and *zipping* (the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

[ankostis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24892177/5240546) in my opinion is the most elegant solution when you have the file on disk.

However, if you do not want to or cannot go the detour of saving and loading from the file system, you can also do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": [73, 36], "position" : ["UCLA", "SUNY"]})

series = df["position"]
series.index = df["name"]
series.to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{'UCLA': 73, 'SUNY': 36}
```